# Is it safe to upgrade postgres major version from client perspective?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have created an application and connected it to Postgres 9,
and then I decide to upgrade to Postgres 14, will my application break, (like some SQL Query/Statement not supported anymore)

Is there any official statement from Postgres author about backward compatibility from the client's perspective?
Will my application keep working without changing anything with all future Postgres versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any official statement from Postgres author about backward compatibility from the client's perspective

All incompatible changes are documented in the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/)

It's not clear from which version you upgrade as "Postgres 9" covers 7 major releases, but you will need to go through each version's release notes. So if "Postgres 9" means 9.0, you need to check the release notes for: 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.

You only need to go through the release notes for the initial major version (`.0`). Minor versions typically don't introduce any incompatible changes.

> Will my application keep working without changing anything with all future Postgres versions?

It's likely, but it's not guaranteed. There have been incompatible changes in the past but the development team tries hard to avoid them. But sometimes it's not possible.

It is mandatory to have an test environment for your application. Then you can upgrade Postgres in that test environment, run all your tests and see if anything is breaking.

This is one of the reasons I prefer to "upgrade early" as the possible number of incompatible changes is much smaller when you go from 13 to 14 compare to going from 9.2 to 14.

[This site](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.0.23&to=14.1) shows you a list of all changes between any two versions and might help going through the list of changes.